# Why IdentityModel JWT library generates the same token when the same Expires is provided?

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have the following code in my application to generate a JWT for authentication purposes in a REST API:

```
    private string GenerateToken(List<Claim> identityFields)
    {
        var key = Convert.FromBase64String(__SECRET);
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key);
        var descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(identityFields.ToArray()),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = handler.CreateJwtSecurityToken(descriptor);
        return handler.WriteToken(token);
    }
```

The "identityFields" parameter is an object with values from the user (which are not relevant here).

My main problem is that, when I sent two request to that method in the same second (I mean, for example, 2019-01-23 14:57:59.827 and 2019-01-23 14:57:59.350), it generates the same JWT for both session (taking in mind that the "identityFields are the same, of course), because the "Expires" property doesn't concern about the milliseconds.

How can solve that issue?

I'm using the official JWT library (System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt), is not custom code.

Thank you!

Comment: why is that an issue?

Comment: @jps because I'm storing that token (along with some other properties) in a Session object in the database, and when I try to get the Session object throught the Token it returns more than one element, and needs to be a single one

Comment: It seems a bit strange to store the token in a database; but you could possible refrain from storing duplicate keys in your database.

Comment: @Jonny yes, finally I added a validation to prevent duplicate tokens. One more question: why storing the token in the database is strange to you? I mean, I need the token so I can get the session data (like the ApplicationId, UserId, etc) and the Token is the only thing that the consumer of the API Rest send me in the Auth header

Comment: why not put `applicationId, userId` into jwt payload itself? that's the purpose of jwt, to carry information.

Comment: @deezg yes, but I need to persist that information (appId, userId, etc) somewhere. So adding a validation in the database works fine for me!

Comment: I store tokens too for same reasons, I hate "holier than thou" responses

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/27/bearer-token-authentication-in-asp-net-core/

Depending on your specific use case you should be able to add custom claims to your token so that you can extrac the needed information directly from the token.

If you need to keep the information secret (since anyone can decode a JWT token) you could add a unique identifier to as a custom claim and use that to look up information in your database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but finally I added a validation to prevent duplicate tokens in the database because I need to persist that extra information somewhere